# Repeating and canceling UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I want to have a `UILocalNotification` firing in my application every minute for a variable number of times and after that, I want to cancel it.

I'm trying to find a parameter that would enable me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Scheduling notification**

*Note the `.repeatInterval` property value.*

```
UILocalNotification *reminder = UILocalNotification.new;
reminder.fireDate = fireDate;
reminder.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
reminder.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
reminder.alertAction = @"Your alert action";
reminder.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
reminder.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminder];
```

2) **Handling notification** (AppDelegate)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    // custom handling code
}
```

*Note: in iOS 8 you have to register for local notifications for the delegate methods to be called.*

3) **Canceling `UILocalNnotification`**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:reminder];
```

4) **Notification distinction**

To keep track of how many times a notification has been received, you have to uniquely identify your notification(s). You can do that by making use of `UILocalNotification` instance `.userInfo` property.

*Example*

```
UILocalNotification *reminder = UILocalNotification.new;
...
reminder.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"custom value" forKey:@"notificationUniqueId"];
...
```

Then, when you receive your notification in delegate method written in *2)*, you can check for notification unique id that you stated in `userInfo` dictionary. Knowing that, you are able to keep track how many times a `UILocalNotification` has been fired and cancel it when appropriate.

Hope that helps!